# Understanding tensorflow behavior when fetching Data from two different data sources with dataset api

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to fetch data from two different `dataset` sources with tensorflow. I have written the following code:

First I have tried the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

iters = []

def return_data1():
    d1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 2000)
    iter1 = d1.make_initializable_iterator()
    iters.append(iter1)
    data1 = iter1.get_next()
    return data1

def return_data2():
    d2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(2000, 4000)
    iter2 = d2.make_initializable_iterator()
    iters.append(iter2)
    data2 = iter2.get_next()
    return data2

test = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool)

data = tf.cond(test, lambda: return_data1(), lambda: return_data2())

iter1 = iters[0]
iter2 = iters[1]

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run([iter1.initializer, iter2.initializer])

    for i in range(2000):
        if i < 1000:
            print(sess.run(data, feed_dict={test: True}), "..")
        else:
            print(sess.run(data, feed_dict={test: False}), "--")
```

And I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Operation 'cond/MakeIterator' has been marked as not fetchable.
```

1- I would like to know why I am getting this behavior.

Then, I have tried to fix my code, so I wrote the following:

```
d1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 2000)
d2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(2000, 4000)

iter1 = d1.make_initializable_iterator()
iter2 = d2.make_initializable_iterator()

data1 = iter1.get_next()
data2 = iter2.get_next()

def return_data1():
    return data1

def return_data2():
    return data2

test = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool)

data = tf.cond(test, lambda: return_data1(), lambda: return_data2())

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run([iter1.initializer, iter2.initializer])

    for i in range(2000):
        if i < 1000:
            print(sess.run(data, feed_dict={test: True}), "..")
        else:
            print(sess.run(data, feed_dict={test: False}), "--")
```

And from the `print`, I get numbers from 1 -> 1000 from the first dataset, but when `i` becomes greater than 1000, it start printing `3000 -> 4000`. Therefore, I have concluded that as the first dataset has been running or as I was has fetched a `1000` element from the second dataset, but they were ignored.

Later, when I fixed my code by moving `data1 = iter1.get_next()` and 
`data2 = iter2.get_next()` into the function definition as:

```
def return_data1():
    data1 = iter1.get_next()
    return data1
```

AND

```
def return_data2():
    data2 = iter2.get_next()
    return data2
```

The code works, and now prints numbers `1 -> 1000` and `2000 -> 3000`.

I would like to understand why this happens so that I avoid similar mistakes in the future.

I have discovered the same kind of problem with the `tf.control_dependency`, which accepts the the operation as an argument, and that operation should not be created outside. This behaviors has confused me a while and yet I would like to know why is that happening with tensorflow.

Second, if I would like to choose from more than two sources of datasets and run them separately, how to do that in tensorflow?

any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to fetch data from multiple dataset separately. Yet I would like know the answer for my other questions regarding the behavior of tensorflow and why should `data2 = iter2.get_next()` should be defined within a method.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

d1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 1000)
iter1 = d1.make_initializable_iterator()

d2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(1000, 2000)
iter2 = d2.make_initializable_iterator()

d3 = tf.data.Dataset.range(2000, 3000)
iter3 = d3.make_initializable_iterator()

d4 = tf.data.Dataset.range(3000, 4000)
iter4 = d4.make_initializable_iterator()

def return_data1_2():
    data1 = iter1.get_next()
    data2 = iter2.get_next()
    return data1, data2

def return_data2_3():
    data2 = iter2.get_next()
    data3 = iter3.get_next()
    return data2, data3

def return_data3_4():
    data3 = iter3.get_next()
    data4 = iter4.get_next()
    return data3, data4

def return_data4_1():
    data4 = iter4.get_next()
    data1 = iter1.get_next()
    return data4, data1

index1 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
index2 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)

data = tf.case(pred_fn_pairs=[
    (tf.logical_and(tf.equal(index1, 1), tf.equal(index2, 2)), lambda: return_data1_2()), 
    (tf.logical_and(tf.equal(index1, 2), tf.equal(index2, 3)), lambda: return_data2_3()),
    (tf.logical_and(tf.equal(index1, 3), tf.equal(index2, 4)), lambda: return_data3_4()),
    (tf.logical_and(tf.equal(index1, 4), tf.equal(index2, 1)), lambda: return_data4_1())], exclusive=False)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run([iter1.initializer, iter2.initializer, iter3.initializer, iter4.initializer])


    for i in range(2000):
        try:
            if i < 500:
                print(sess.run(data, feed_dict={index1: 1, index2: 2}), "1-2")
            elif i < 1000:
                print(sess.run(data, feed_dict={index1: 2, index2: 3}), "2-3")
            elif i < 1500:
                print(sess.run(data, feed_dict={index1: 3, index2: 4}), "3-4")
            elif i < 2000:
                print(sess.run(data, feed_dict={index1: 4, index2: 1}), "4-1")
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError as error:
            print("error")
```